# Alternate implementations of QSharedDataPointer and QSharedData

Tags: c++, qt, qshareddata

I was wondering if anyone has come across a system like QSharedDataPointer and QSharedData for implicit sharing, which is appropriate for use with the pimpl idiom, in an alternative library to Qt?

I have been trying to avoid adding extra dependencies to my system if that's possible and am simply wondering what my options might be.

Comment: They're simple enough you can reimplement those classes yourself, or extract them from Qt... (usual license warnings apply).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A similar system can be found [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C++_Idioms/Copy-on-write). The main difference is that a boost::shared_ptr is used for having a reference counted shared pointer instead of requiring that the object inherit from a supplied class which provides the reference counting functionality.

Although I have not yet tried it, it may have a slightly higher overhead compared to the qSharedDataPointer due to the boost::shared_ptr dereference, however the cost is a trade off against it's more convenient usage.

Answer (score 1):

Adobe provides a `copy_on_write<T>` header in their [stlab](https://stlab.cc/libraries/stlab2Fcopy_on_write.hpp/copy_on_write3CT3E/) library.